# Combination patterns - how to calculate?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a bag of 9 different colored balls, and I want to calculate the probabilities of all the patterns there can be. If I picked 4 balls (with replacement), I could get the following patterns:

1. all 4 are the same color (eg RRRR)
2. 3 are the same color, and 1 is different (RRRY)
3. 2 are the same color, and the other two are the same color (RRYY)
4. 2 are the same color, and the other two are different
   (RRYB)
5. all 4 are different colors (RYBG)

I've actually produced and sorted all the possible combinations, so I know what my end numbers should be. I did that so I could try to understand how to get to the correct number, but I'
m not having much luck, and that won't work once I start getting to larger groups (pulling 5, ,6, 7, 8, or 9).

Calculating cat 1 is easy - it's always 9. There are 9 options for the first ball, and then 1 option (the matching color) for all of the rest.

Calculating the last category is also easy: 9*8*7*6*....

Its the intermediates that are causing me issues. I'm not understanding how to get there. For example, my count showed 216 possibilities where 3 balls were the same color and the other was a different color. To me, this seems like it would be 9*1*1*8, but that's definitely NOT 216.

How do I calculate these? Especially for larger groups, it will be vital that I understand this - I can't generate all 0.53/5/43/387 billion possible combinations.

Comment: Given that you calculated the last category as $9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6$ that implies to me that you are interested in counting where order matters.  Note that for $3$ to be the same color and $1$ to be different, *not only* do you have situations like `RRRY` but you also have situations like `RYRR` and `YRRR` and so on.  Similarly $2$ of the same color and the remaining $2$ of a different color could have been `RRYY` or it could have been `RYRY` or `RYYR` etc...

Comment: Order doesn't matter, I was just trying to account for different colors. the first could be any of the 9 colors, but then the next would have to be one of the 8 remaining, and so on. For combinations taken 3 at a time, I got the correct count of 2 same, 1 diff (216) by multiplying C(9,2) by combinations with replacement C(3,2) (i.e. 36 * 6), but when I tried the same method for other patterns, no good. C(9,3)*Cr(4,3) = 1680, not 216.

Comment: If order doesn't matter then the last category wouldn't be $9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6$ possibilities, it would be $\binom{9}{4}$ possibilities.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Since I want the count of all possibilities that meet the requirements, I do want permutations. RRYR and RRRY and RYRR and YRRR and so on. They all fall into the same category, but I need to know total # of permutations. How to calculate those is where I'm stuck.This is why I get confused with the combinations too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event that order matters:

- All balls same color: $9$
- Three balls same color, one ball different: $\binom{4}{3}\cdot 9\cdot \binom{1}{1}\cdot 8 = 4\cdot 9\cdot 8 = 288$
- Two balls same color, remaining two balls same color: $\binom{9}{2}\binom{4}{2}= 216$
- Two balls same color, remaining two balls different colors: $\binom{4}{2}\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7 = 3024$
- All balls different colors: $9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6 = 3024$

Adding these together gives: $9+288+216+3024+3024 = 6561$ which happens to equal $9^4$, the total number of arrangements of four balls where order matters, just as we should have expected.

---

More details for the third case for instance where two balls are of the same color and remaining two balls are of a same different color.

We first pick which two colors appear simultaneously.  This can be done in $\binom{9}{2}$ ways.  Now that we see what colors were selected, there is an unambiguous color whose name comes first alphabetically.  We pick which two spaces are occupied by that color ball.  This can be done in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.  The remaining spaces are then occupied by balls of the other selected color.  We get then a count of $\binom{9}{2}\binom{4}{2}=216$ ways.

Alternatively, we could pick the color of the first ball.  We then pick which position among the remaining three matches in color.  We then pick the remaining color for the remaining positions.  This can be done in $9\cdot \binom{3}{2}\cdot 8=216$ ways which we see is equal to what we got before.

---

In response to comment.

9 colors 5 at a time:

- All balls same color: $9$
- Four balls same color, one ball different: $\binom{5}{4}\cdot 9\cdot 8 = 360$
- Three balls same color, remaining two balls same: $\binom{5}{3}\cdot 9\cdot 8 =  720$
- Three balls same color, remaining two balls different: $\binom{5}{3}\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7 = 5040$
- Two balls same, Two other balls same, one ball different: $\binom{9}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\cdot 7 = 7560$
- Two balls same, remaining all different: $9\cdot \binom{5}{2}\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6 = 30240$
- All balls different: $9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5 = 15120$

Checking, we get $9+360+720+5040+7560+30240+15120=59049=9^5$, just as we expected.

Your errors were doing something totally out of left field for the 3/2 case that I can't explain your thought process... adding? $\binom{3}{2}$?  Where did those come from?

The other mistake was much more common.  In the 2/2/1 case, you did "Pick two spaces for the *first* color" then "pick what the *first* color actually is" followed by "pick two spaces for the *second* color" followed by "pick what the *second* color actually is" finally followed by "pick the color for the last space."

This is incorrect and overcounts because you can use different sequences of answers to get the same result.  We can't tell which was the "first" color and which was the "second" color after they have already been distributed and your counting makes the difference between "first" and "second" color somehow significant when it shouldn't have been.

For example:

"First two spaces": $\underline{\star}~\underline{\star}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~} \rightarrow$ "Red": $\underline{R}~\underline{R}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}\rightarrow$ "Third and fourth spaces": $\underline{R}~\underline{R}~\underline{\star}~\underline{\star}~\underline{~}\rightarrow$ "Yellow": $\underline{R}~\underline{R}~\underline{Y}~\underline{Y}~\underline{~}\rightarrow$ "Blue": $\underline{R}~\underline{R}~\underline{Y}~\underline{Y}~\underline{B}$

gave the same result as:

"Third and fourth spaces": $\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{\star}~\underline{\star}~\underline{~} \rightarrow$ "Yellow": $\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{Y}~\underline{Y}~\underline{~}\rightarrow$ "First two spaces": $\underline{\star}~\underline{\star}~\underline{Y}~\underline{Y}~\underline{~}\rightarrow$ "Red": $\underline{R}~\underline{R}~\underline{Y}~\underline{Y}~\underline{~}\rightarrow$ "Blue": $\underline{R}~\underline{R}~\underline{Y}~\underline{Y}~\underline{B}$

Instead, select both colors used for two balls *simultaneously*, then for the earlier appearing alphabetically pick which spaces it uses.

$\binom{9}{2}$ to choose the colors, $\binom{5}{2}$ to pick the spaces for the alphabetically first selected color, then $\binom{3}{2}$ to pick the spaces for the remaining selected color, finally $7$ choices for the final color, giving $\binom{9}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\cdot 7 = 7560$ arrangements.

Alternatively, pick the location of the singleton color and what color it is.  Then in the furthest left remaining available position pick a color for it.  Pick one of the remaining positions to match the color.  Finally pick a color for the remaining positions, giving a total of $5\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 3\cdot 7=7560$, same as before.

In both of these correct ways of counting, we make sure that there is an unambiguous single way of arriving at each outcome where we can't rearrange our answers in a way to give the same result like we could for yours.  We accomplished that by noting that there is an unambiguous "first" color when ordering them alphabetically in the first method.  We accomplished that by noting there is an unambiguous "furthest left" remaining available space in the second method.

Comment: Too see if I understand this: (4/3)⋅9⋅(1/1)⋅8=4⋅9⋅8=288 - that's (4,3) for number of arrangements of the Rs * 9 possible colors * (1,1) for the arrangements of the Y, with 8 possible colors. And then (9,2) is the selection of 2 colors x (4,2) the number of ways those two colors could be arranged. Wouldn't that include possibilities where the 2 selected color were the same in the (9,2)?

Comment: "Wouldn't that include possibilities where the 2 selected color were the same in the (9,2)?"  If you are asking if $\binom{9}{2}$ counts things where our two selected colors were `red` and `red`, no that is not possible.  This is a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  You might be confusing it with the multichoose function or with $9^2$, something different.  If you are asking if we overcounted arrangements, no we did not because we take advantage of the fact that after choosing there is an unambiguous order we can apply to them, e.g. alphabetically.

Comment: I tried to apply this logic and I failed. For 9 colors, 5 at a time: pattern 5 (all same) = 9, pattern 4/1 = c(5,4) * 9 * 8 = 360, pattern 3/2 = c(5,3) * 9 + c(3,2) * 8 = 2160, pattern 3/1/1 = c(5,3) * 9 * 8 * 7 = 5040, pattern 2/2/1 = c (5,2) * 9 * c(3,2) * 8 * 7 = 15120, pattern 2/1/1/1 = c(5,2) * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 = 30240, and final (all different) = 9*8*7*6*5 = 15120. Total is 68049, way more than the 59049 it should be. What did I mess up?

Comment: @graidan added response above

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz! I think I get it now. As to your where did I get the c(3,2) fromI was thinking in the same way you described - pick a color (9) * c(5,3) ways for them to appear, * 8 (remaining colors) * c(3,2) ways to appear  - but it should have been c(2,2)=1 because there's only 1 way for the same color to appear in both slots (durr). On to groups of 6 - I'll say something if I still mess it up.

Comment: So I'm going with the "pick a color * how many ways" approach, because that makes clear sense to me, but it doesn't always work and I don't understand why. For example, taken 6 at a time, pattern is 2/2/2. That seems to me like it should be 9*C(6,2)*8*C(4,2)*7 = 45360. Then 2/2/1/1 would be 9*C(6,2)*8*C(4,2)*7*6 = 272160. I've repeated this method for every pattern, but I still come ~175k above possible total.

Comment: @graidan read again what I've already written.  You are incorrectly and unintentionally putting emphasis on which color is chosen "first" when there shouldn't be any such emphasis.   If we had an arrangement RRYYBB, which did I choose first?  You can't know for sure.  Whichever you guess, I could say you were right.  I could also say you were wrong and give a different sequence that leads to that arrangement.  See the example above with RRYYB.

Comment: On the other hand, you *can* clearly tell me which color is first alphabetically from what I've chosen.  You could also tell me clearly the order in which colors first appear from left to right.  My suggested methods if counting above take advantage of these facts and come to the correct count, having successfully avoided overcounting by providing an unambiguous clear way to go from an arrangement to the corresponding sequence of choices and vice versa.